# Query to get names of databases, count of tables, count of indexes, size of the database and owner of database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing, count

Is there a query to get names of databases, count of tables, count of indexes, size of the DB and owner of DB on MSSQL? I looked at many solutions but could not find any, where I could get the count of indexes on the DB as well.

Comment: Hint:  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables`.

Answer (score 0):

Tables in database

```
    sp_MSForEachTable 'DECLARE @t AS VARCHAR(MAX); 
    SELECT @t = CAST(COUNT(1) as VARCHAR(MAX)) 
    + CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + ''?'' FROM ? ; PRINT @t'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can do all of these things from SQL like so:

Get the database name:

```
select DB_NAME()
```

Get the number of tables:

```
select count(*) from sys.tables
```

Get the number of indexes:

```
select count(*) from sys.indexes
```

Get the amount of space used:

```
exec sp_spaceused
```

Get the user name of the database owner:

```
select distinct suser_sname( owner_sid ) from sys.databases
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd tend to use Powershell for something like this. Here's my swing at it:

```
push-location;
import-module sqlps -disablenamechecking;
pop-location;

$s = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server 'yourServer';

foreach ($db in $s.Databases | where {$_.IsAccessible -eq $true} ) {
    $r = @{TableCount = 0;
        IndexCount = 0;
        Name = $db.Name;
        Size = $db.Size
    }
    $table_count = 0;
    $index_count = 0;
    foreach ($table in $db.Tables) {
        $r.TableCount += 1;
        $r.IndexCount += $table.Indexes.Count
    }
    $r | select-object @{name='name';expression={$_.name}},
        @{name='size';expression={$_.size}},
        @{name='TableCount';expression={$_.TableCount}},
        @{name='IndexCount';expression={$_.IndexCount}};
}
```